# How to GROUP BY records with specific Columns only

Tags: sql-server

I have this query containing `GROUP BY` clause.

I only want to apply GROUP BY on FolioNumber only because the data in other columns is changing rapidly for same record due to UPDATE.

Here is the sample Query, I hope you don't need sample data and understand the query structure as this pretty simple.

```
SELECT MAX(TransactionNo) [TransactionNo], [FolioNo], [SalesOrderDate], [Center], [Company], [Customer],
       [DeliveryAddress], [OfficialPhoneNo], [Item], [OrderQty], [UnitPrice], [Description], [FinishType], 
       [Remarks], [OrderNo], [BookNo], [CustomerAddress], [Customer], [DeliveryDate], [SalePerson]
       [Status], [Discount], [NetAmount], [GrossAmount], [InvoiceDiscount], [GSTTax], [DateFrom], [DateTo]

FROM tblPageIndex 
GROUP BY [FolioNo]
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: No @YuriyF as I have not included any other column in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: So you want to group by more than one column?

Comment: No @YuriyF I only want to GROUP only with FolioNo

Comment: You want to apply group by is understood but what result you want is not understood. if you can provide some sample table data and sample output, it will be easier to know what's wrong and where

Answer (score 2):

I think you want data associated with each `FoliyoNo` where `TransactionNo` is maximum.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to group the rows based on `FoliyoNo` and select the row with maximum value for `TransactionNo`

```
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT [TransactionNo], [FolioNo], [SalesOrderDate], [Center], [Company], [Customer],
       [DeliveryAddress], [OfficialPhoneNo], [Item], [OrderQty], [UnitPrice], 
       [Description], [FinishType], [Remarks], [OrderNo], [BookNo], [CustomerAddress], 
       [Customer], [DeliveryDate], [SalePerson]
       [Status], [Discount], [NetAmount], [GrossAmount], [InvoiceDiscount], 
       [GSTTax], [DateFrom], [DateTo],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [FolioNo] ORDER BY TransactionNo DESC) AS RN

FROM tblPageIndex 

)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

From the comments, it turns out to know that you want all the rows with maximum `TransactionNo` in each `FoliyoNo`.

So you can change the `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes you're right but it is returning only one row. I think I need to look deeper into your answer.

Comment: I guess this will only show one Row everytime as we have RN = 1, but there could be multiple rows against same FolioNo so that's no gonna work

Comment: If for example there are two or more TransactionNo that are maximum for a given folio number and you want both then change ROW_NUMBER to RANK.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo salman is right. You can use RANK instead of Row_number. If yes, feel free to edit the answer or update me ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Over clause. find below sample query might will help you. As you have not provide any data set for unit test.

```
SELECT MAX(TransactionNo) over (partition by FolioNo) as  [TransactionNo], [FolioNo], [SalesOrderDate], [Center], [Company], [Customer],
       [DeliveryAddress], [OfficialPhoneNo], [Item], [OrderQty], [UnitPrice], [Description], [FinishType], 
       [Remarks], [OrderNo], [BookNo], [CustomerAddress], [Customer], [DeliveryDate], [SalePerson]
       [Status], [Discount], [NetAmount], [GrossAmount], [InvoiceDiscount], [GSTTax], [DateFrom], [DateTo]

FROM tblPageIndex
```